# Syntax error: unexpected ;

Tags: php, laravel

I am running the following code using if statements. My syntax so far looks right but i get an error saying

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'
at $request->session()->put('success');
```

It looks okay. Could someone tell me where I am wrong. 
My code is as follows:

```
<?php

if (Hash::check($password, $hashedPassword->password)) {
    $role_type = DB::select('select role_type from users where email = ?', [$email]);
    if ($role_type === 'Administrator') {
        $request->session()->put('success');
        return redirect()->route('admin');
    } else if ($role_type == - 'Staff') {
        $request->session()->put('success');
        return redirect()->route('staff');
    } else ($role_type === 'User') {
        $request->session()->put('success');
        return redirect()->route('user');
    };
} else {
    return redirect()->route('login')->with('login_error', 'Invalid credentials entered');
};
```

Comment: `else if ($role_type ==- 'Staff') {` you got "-"

Comment: I saw that error and corrected it but still gives me the same error of syntax @Kasnady

Comment: @jptl431 check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48942407/7117697

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `if` in `} else ($role_type === 'User') {` line it should be `} else if($role_type === 'User') {`

```
if (Hash::check($password, $hashedPassword->password)) {
    $role_type = DB::select('select role_type from users where 
            email = ?', [$email]);
    if ($role_type === 'Administrator') {
        $request->session()->put('success');
        return redirect()->route('admin');
    } else if ($role_type == - 'Staff') {
        $request->session()->put('success');
        return redirect()->route('staff');
    } else if($role_type === 'User') {
        $request->session()->put('success');
        return redirect()->route('user');
    }
} else {
    return redirect()->route('login')->with('login_error', 'Invalid 
            credentials entered');
}
```

Comment: Thanks bruv! Worked perfectly! But shouldn't there be an ending else after all the 'else ifs'